# epipolar geometry / stereo vision using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing epipolar geometry using openCV. 
(the ultimate goal is estimating world coordinate of model or depth information from two images taken from different viewpoints using same camera)

However i am struggling with estimating fundamental matrix and essential matrix that are used in epipolar geometry.

[image: corresponding points with different viewpoint of camera]

As shown above, I captured two images with different viewpoints (same camera). The same color points are corresponding points.

the exact coordinates are ( i write it if you want to verify)

points1 : left

```
points1.push_back(Point2f(157,223));
points1.push_back(Point2f(190,312));
points1.push_back(Point2f(157,541));
points1.push_back(Point2f(136,443));
points1.push_back(Point2f(355,374));
points1.push_back(Point2f(346,406));
points1.push_back(Point2f(252,410));
points1.push_back(Point2f(254,379));
```

points2 : right

```
points2.push_back(Point2f(190,188)); 
points2.push_back(Point2f(303,284)); 
points2.push_back(Point2f(252,512)); 
points2.push_back(Point2f(166,420)); 
points2.push_back(Point2f(422,311));
points2.push_back(Point2f(412,339));
points2.push_back(Point2f(341,366));
points2.push_back(Point2f(345,335));
```

using points,

Mat FundamentalMatrix = findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, FM_RANSAC, 1.0, 0.99);

openCV function is used to calculate fundamental matrix. however the calculated fundamental is strange I guess.

[image: calculated fundamental matrices and constraints]

- left : using FM_RANSAC, right : using CV_FM_8POINTS

the calculated fundamental matrix should satisfy x'T F x = 0

where x' is (u2, v2, 1)^T and x is (u1, v1, 1) ^T

with u1, v1 = points 1 coordinate and u2, v2 = points 2 coordinate.

as illustrated above, i calculated the x'T F x = 0. however the third case (third corresponding points), it is not zero.

of course i tried different method.

```
Mat FundamentalMatrix = findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, CV_FM_8POINT);
```

is also tried.

however for this case, all of corresponding points do not satisfy constraint.

whats the problem? is there any mistake i did? (what i am thinking is the 8 points are still insufficient, there should be more points)

In addition, I estimated poses of the model (extrinsic matrices) for different viewpoints. and perform camera calibration. Thus E1 (extrinsic matrix for viewpoint 1) , E2, K (intrinsic matrix) are estimated. (I guess those are almost exact. because if i project a model point using E1, E2 and k, then it is projected at correct point on image).
--> Then I estimate essential matrix E = K^T F K . 
the E should satisfy determinant of E should 0 and has eigenvalue (1,1,0) or (sigma, sigma, 1)
However it wasn't.

What are the problems?

Comment: I experiment with more points, and it looks like satisfying constraints. I guess the eight points i chose makes singular value when calculating fundamental matrix. After I confirm results, I'll write comments again.

Comment: Ransac is the way to go - but it requires many more point correspondences. Ransac essentially runs the eightpoint algorithm under the hood on randomly picked correspondences and picks the best fundamental matrix of all the ones it generates.

However, with hand-picked point correspondences, I believe the eight-point algorithm should work perfectly.